# Problemas em String e Case

Tags: c, string, printf, case

Sou iniciante em programação há pouco tempo e tenho uma tarefa da faculdade na qual devo criar um sistema de cadastros que receba as entradas os dados dos clientes e em seguida numa outra opção que imprima na tela( case 2) essas informações.

Mas estou com problemas na hora de imprimir estas *strings*, onde acredito eu aparecem os locais de memória delas e diversos caracteres aleatórios.

Gostaria de saber o que posso fazer para que as *Strings* sejam lidas corretamente e se a `return main()` ou se o `&` antes da variável, tem algo em relação a esse problema. Desculpem pelo código bagunçado e meio estranho

```
int main(void) {

    int opcao;
    cliente cadastro[100];
    int i;
    char sair;

    printf("\n1- Clientes");
    printf("\n2- Automoveis");
    printf("\n3- Tabela de precos e classificacao");
    printf("\n4- Locacao");
    printf("\n\n\n\tDigite a opcao desejada:  ");
    scanf("%d", &opcao);

    switch (opcao)
    {
    case 1:
        system("cls");
        printf("\n1- Cadastro de Clientes");
        printf("\n2- Detalhes do Clientes");
        printf("\n3- Alterar/Excluir Clientes");
        printf("\n\n\n\tDigite a opcao desejada:  ");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);

        switch (opcao)
        {
        case 1:
            do
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("\nCadastro de Clientes\n");
                printf("\nDigite o Codigo do Cliente:  ");
                scanf("  %d", &i);
                cadastro[i].codigo = i;
                system("cls");
                printf("\n Codigo do Cliente:  %d\n", cadastro[i].codigo);
                printf("\n Nome:  ");
                scanf("  %[^\n]s", &cadastro[i].nome);
                printf("\n RG:  ");
                scanf(" %s", &cadastro[i].rg);
                printf("\n CPF:  ");
                scanf(" %s", &cadastro[i].cpf);
                printf("\n Endereco:  ");
                scanf("  %[^\n]s", &cadastro[i].endereco);
                printf("\n Carteira de Habilitacao:  ");
                scanf(" %[^\n]s", &cadastro[i].carteira_hab);
                system("cls");
                printf("\nCadastro Realizado com sucesso!");
                printf("\n\n\t\t\tDeseja Realizar outro cadastro? S / N:  ");
                scanf(" %c", &sair);

            } while (sair != 'n');
            system("cls");
            return main();

            break;

        case 2:
            printf("\nDetalhes do Clientes");
            printf("Digite o código do cliente:  ");
            scanf("%d", &i);
            printf("\nNome:  %s", &cadastro[i].nome);



        default:
            break;
        }

    default:
        break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Coloque também a estrutura `cliente` para se saber como foram definidas as strings. Mas uma string definida como `char[]` ou `char*` não leva o `&` no `scanf`, pois já é um ponteiro. Mas se for `char*` precisa de ser alocada antes de ser utilizada

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algumas sugestões no teu código:

```
int main() {
    int opcao, opcao2; //nao use a mesma variavel para os dois switchs
    cliente cadastro[100];
    int i;
    char sair;

    //precisa envolver todo este código em um do-while ao inves de chamar recursivamente a funcao main
    printf("\n1- Clientes");
    printf("\n2- Automoveis");
    printf("\n3- Tabela de precos e classificacao");
    printf("\n4- Locacao");
    printf("\n\n\n\tDigite a opcao desejada:  ");
    scanf("%d", &opcao);

    switch (opcao) {
        case 1: {//faltava uma chave aqui
            system("cls");
            printf("\n1- Cadastro de Clientes");
            printf("\n2- Detalhes do Clientes");
            printf("\n3- Alterar/Excluir Clientes");
            printf("\n\n\n\tDigite a opcao desejada:  ");
            scanf("%d", &opcao2);
            switch (opcao2) {
                case 1:
                    do {
                        system("cls");
                        printf("\nCadastro de Clientes\n");
                        printf("\nDigite o Codigo do Cliente:  ");
                        scanf("  %d", &i);
                        cadastro[i].codigo = i;
                        system("cls");
                        printf("\n Codigo do Cliente:  %d\n", cadastro[i].codigo);
                        printf("\n Nome:  ");
                        scanf("%[^\n]s", cadastro[i].nome);//sem & quando for string
                        printf("\n RG:  ");
                        scanf("%s", cadastro[i].rg);//sem & quando for string
                        printf("\n CPF:  ");
                        scanf(" %s", cadastro[i].cpf);//sem & quando for string
                        printf("\n Endereco:  ");
                        scanf("%[^\n]s", cadastro[i].endereco);//sem & quando for string
                        printf("\n Carteira de Habilitacao:  ");
                        scanf("%[^\n]s", cadastro[i].carteira_hab);//sem & quando for string
                        system("cls");
                        printf("\nCadastro Realizado com sucesso!");
                        printf("\n\n\t\t\tDeseja Realizar outro cadastro? S / N:  ");
                        scanf("%c", &sair);
                    } while (sair != 'n');
                    system("cls");              
                    break;
                case 2: { //faltava uma chave aqui
                    printf("\nDetalhes do Clientes");
                    printf("Digite o código do cliente:  ");
                    scanf("%d", &i);
                    printf("\nNome:  %s", &cadastro[i].nome);
                }
        }
    } 
}
```